# Bash for loop with range {#..#}

Tags: command-line, bash

The {#..#} generate a sequence of numbers or chars, similarly to range() in Python.
If I execute the command `echo {1..5}` in the command line I have:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Instead the following bash script doesn't work as expected.

```
for i in {1..3};
do
    echo "Iteration $i"
done
```

will print:

```
Iteration {1..3}
```

Why?
*I could use `seq` but I read it's outdate (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/)

Comment: This error occur if the script is executed by the "sh" command (try using "bash").

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've tried your code (copy paste into a terminal) and it produced a different result from what you posted:

```
for i in {1..3};
do
    echo "Iteration $i"
done
#---OUTPUT BELOW---
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3
```

Im using Linux Mint 12 Lisa (derived from Ubuntu) with bash version *4.2.10(1)-release*

Comment: You are right! I thought sh and bash were the same thing..

Comment: no, bash and sh are quite different... bash is more capable than sh, it was made on the shoulders of sh :) although they both have a good degree of compatibility, they also have its differences

Comment: note that you can do nested lists like for var in {{i..j},{l..m}};do echo $var;done if you need irregular sequence such as 1 2 3 7 8 9

Comment: Note that on some distros `/bin/sh` IS actually pointing at bash, on Debian and Ubuntu it is typically pointing to `/bin/dash` which is mostly POSIX compliant but doesn't support all the same syntax as Bash.